# How to select from table one with all records from table 2

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to display all records that table 1 contains, each record with all the records from table 2 :

```
Table 1

company  adress
------------------
 A        AdressX 
 B        AdressY
 C        AdressZ

Table 2

Product   Price
----------------
 P1        50 
 P2        60

Result :

company  Product
----------------
 A        P1 
 A        P2
 B        P1
 B        P2
 C        P1
 C        P2
```

Comment: Use Cross APPLY

Answer (score 2):

That would be a cross join.

```
SELECT t1.company,
       t2.product
       FROM [table 1] t1
            CROSS JOIN [table 2] t2
       ORDER BY t1.company,
                t2.product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `CROSS APPLY` this exected output is possible:

```
SELECT T1.company, T2.Product
FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY Table2  T2
ORDER BY T1.company, T2.Product
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83701cc78f66585f548737741ff5d2c2)

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (company VARCHAR (1), adress VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @Table1 (company, adress) VALUES
('A', 'AdressX'), 
('B', 'AdressY'),
('C', 'AdressZ');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Product VARCHAR (2),   Price INT);

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Product, Price) VALUES
('P1', 50), 
('P2', 60);

SELECT T1.company, T2.Product
FROM @Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY @Table2  T2
ORDER BY T1.company, T2.Product
```

Output:

```
company Product
---------------
A       P1
A       P2
B       P1
B       P2
C       P1
C       P2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select all data from both tables (not linked or related).

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 1
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT * 
FROM Table 2
) AS Table 2
```

If there is a foreign key, you can use a `LEFT JOIN (SELECT)`